# TypeError: providedScope.$new is not a function - angular bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, meanjs

I have been following the official guides [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) but am still getting the error. A user on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/5962) experienced the same issue but did not mention how it was resolved, only that there was an error in his code calling his factory and I wasn't able to figure out anything from his [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ona2O9zdhdI7zyL18bX2?p=info).

**Controller:**

```
function ActivitiesController($scope, $state, $window, Authentication, activity, $uibModal, $uibModalInstance) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.authentication = Authentication;
    vm.activity = activity;
    vm.openModal = openModal;
    vm.okOnModal = okOnModal;
    vm.cancelOnModal = cancelOnModal;

    function openModal() {
        $uibModal.open({
            template: "<div class='modal-header'>"
                        + "<h3 class='modal-title' id='modal-title'>Friends</h3>"
                    + "</div>"
                    + "<div class='modal-body list-group' id='modal-body'>"
                        + "<a ng-repeat='friend in vm.friends' class='list-group-item'>"
                            + "<img class='friend-user-profile-picture' ng-src='{{ friend.friend.profileImageURL }}' alt='{{ friend.friend.displayName }}'>"
                            + "<h4 class='list-group-item-heading' ng-bind='friend.friend.displayName'></h4>"
                            + "<small class='list-group-item-text' ng-bind='friend.friend.username'></small>"
                            + "<p class='list-group-item-text' ng-bind='friend.friend.email'></p>"
                            + "<input type='checkbox'>"
                        + "</a>"
                    + "</div>"
                    + "<div class='modal-footer'>"
                        + "<button class='btn btn-primary' type='button' ng-click='vm.okOnModal()'>OK</button>"
                        + "<button class='btn btn-warning' type='button' ng-click='vm.cancelOnModal()'>Cancel</button>"
                    + "</div>",
            size: 'lg',
            scope: vm
        });
    }

    function okOnModal() {
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    }

    function cancelOnModal() {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="vm.openModal()">Share with...</button>
```

The error is in `ui.bootstrap-tpls` here:

```
var modalScope = providedScope.$new();
```

**Dependencies:**

- Angular: `1.4.8` *(upgraded from `0.3`)*
- Angular-bootstrap: `2.4.0` *(upgraded from `0.13.4`)*
- Bootstrap: `3.3.7`
- MEAN.JS: `0.4.2`

Reading on MEAN.JS docs, `0.4.2` uses angular-ui `0.13.4` which does not support `$uibModal`. Because of not supporting it, that's why I upgraded to `2.4.0`. There is no mention of MEAN.JS `0.4.2` not supporting angular-ui `2.4.0` but could that be the potential reason?



**EDIT:**

I've ruled out that it's down to the dependency versions as I have changed back to the default ones that come with '0.4.2' in the MEAN.JS stack *(so using `$modal` instead of `$uibModal`)* and I get a similar error of:

> TypeError: (modalOptions.scope || $rootScope).$new is not a function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`vm` is provided as parent scope for the modal. That's the problem, because `vm` is not a scope. It is a controller instance and an object on current scope (if `controllerAs` syntax is used).

`vm` isn't supposed to be interchangeable with `$scope`. It should be:

```
scope: $scope
```

Comment: Yes, I figured this out just moments before you posted but will accept as it is the correct answer. Thank you!